# How to apply formula across multiple time series data in r?

Tags: r, time-series

I download some stocks and apply SMA function to them(hat tip Josh Ulrich)

```
library(quantmod)
e <- new.env()
getSymbols('GOOG;FB', from='2000-01-01', env=e)
close <- cbind(Cl(GOOG),Cl(FB))
smacheck <- do.call(merge, eapply(e, function(x) SMA(Cl(x), 50)))



sig1<-ifelse(close<smacheck,1,0)

   Error in .xts(e, .index(e1), .indexCLASS = indexClass(e1), .indexFORMAT = indexFormat(e1),  : 
  index is not in  increasing order
```

I would like to apply this formula across the two time series, but I get the previous error

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do or what you want the output to be.

Comment: I want to compare 'close' to 'smacheck' across time series

Comment: You don't need `ifelse`. `sig1 <- close < smacheck` works.

Comment: I need output to be either a  1 for TRUE or a 0 for FALSE

Comment: I know you do. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I did, thank you. running the code sig1<-close<smacheck gives me either TRUE or FALSE as output, not 1 or 0

Comment: *sigh* run the rest of your code, or multiply `sig1` by a number so it prints the way you want. `TRUE` and `FALSE` are just `1` and `0`.

Comment: May God bless you, thanks,  _sigh_